Kafka Producer Error --> System.InvalidOperationException
So I am sending about 300 records every 3 seconds and I am seeing error message :
System.InvalidOperation:Failed to create thread: Result too large(#)
at Confluent.Kafka.ProducerBuilder`2.Build()
I Believe this is caused because there are too many messages in the Queue , is there a way to resolve this issue?
Code Snippet:
await producerBuilder(topic,new Message<Null,object>)
.ContinueWith(
task => {
if(task.IsFaulted) 
  {
   //Do Something
  }
}
producerBuilder.Flush(FlushTimeout);


which version of confluent kafka dotnet do you have?

Please share a [mcve].

@IvanPetrov I have version 2.5.2 of Confluent.Kafka and I am using Version 4.8 of Microsoft .NET Framework

Each Producer has as an implementation detail - a dedicated thread to itself for polling, which is created when it is constructed -> prodBuilder.Build()
=> Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    try {
        ....
}, ct, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

which could explain part of the exception message you are getting:
System.InvalidOperation:Failed to create thread: 

So my suspicion is that you are creating fresh producers which you do not dispose properly, so available threads for polling are exhausted.
There is also this github issue for the librdkafka library that Confluent.Kafka is a wrapper around - where it's hinted that too many producers may produce similar errors:

Any way, librdkafka creates a number of threads per instance
internally and with your number of instances you are hitting the
thread / proc limit. See here:
Maximum number of threads per process in Linux?


thanks for the response . should I do producerBuilder.Dispose() after every call

@user6424058 maybe try to have the producer as field that is long living.
